# AWS Sagemaker. How to pass data_capture_config parameter to Pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to monitorize my data so I need to use the DataCaptureConfig object in Sagemaker. The point is that I'm using a Pipeline object that include all my steps. In the [documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_model_monitoring.html) it seems that the only way to use the DataCaptureConfig is passing in in the Model.deploy() step, but I do not have access to this step because I'm using the Pipeline. Is there any other way to do it?

I'm not able to find documentation, examples or some clarification looking at the Sagemaker's python SDK source code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Data Capture for Batch or Real-Time Inference? For Batch you can reference the following example: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-mlops-batch/blob/main/2.SageMakerPipeline-ModelMonitoring-DataQuality-BatchTransform.ipynb. Here you can define a transform and monitor step and pass in your data quality config to this step.

```
job_config = CheckJobConfig(role=role)
data_quality_config = DataQualityCheckConfig(
    baseline_dataset=transform_input_param,
    dataset_format=DatasetFormat.csv(header=False),
    output_s3_uri=batch_monitor_reports_output_path,
)

from sagemaker.workflow.monitor_batch_transform_step import MonitorBatchTransformStep

transform_and_monitor_step = MonitorBatchTransformStep(
    name="MonitorCustomerChurnDataQuality",
    transform_step_args=transform_arg,
    monitor_configuration=data_quality_config,
    check_job_configuration=job_config,
    monitor_before_transform=True,
    # if violation is detected in the monitoring, you can skip it and continue running batch transform
    fail_on_violation=False,
    supplied_baseline_statistics=lambda_getmodel_step.properties.Outputs["s3uriStatistics"],
    supplied_baseline_constraints=lambda_getmodel_step.properties.Outputs["s3uriConstraints"],
)
```

For parameters you can pass in similar to the following code for any metadata you want to inject:

```
from sagemaker.workflow.parameters import (
    ParameterBoolean,
    ParameterInteger,
    ParameterString,
)
```